Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:testClasses' as task 'testClasses' not found in project ':app'
I try to implement Google instruction to connect Firebase with default project setting to Android Java project.
Google instruction
After I carefully implement step-by-step Google instruction, I have received first error "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1" - Attempt to implement Google instruction to connect Firebase failed - "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1""
After I try to implement Google team advice and commented first line in Gradle file - I receive new error "Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:testClasses' as task 'testClasses' not found in project ':app'."
What will my next step to connect Firebase to default Android Java project with all default project setting?
After I try to implement Google team advice and commented first line in Gradle file - I receive new error "Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:testClasses' as task 'testClasses' not found in project ':app'."
What will my next step? What I need to do to connect Firebase to default Java project with all default project setting?

I found solution. I don't know why, but my Gradle cache contains this class.
So, solution is very simple. Just delete cache:
Gradle cache
